# Ruby on Rails 3: has_one association testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I may have my associations messed up. I have the following models: User and UserProfiles.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user_profile, :dependent => :destroy
    attr_accessible :email
end

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I have a column named "user_id" in my user_profiles table.

My factory is setup like so:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email "test@test.com"
end

Factory.sequence :email do |n|
  "person-#{n}@example.com"
end

Factory.define :user_profile do |user_profile|
  user_profile.address_line_1 "123 Test St"
  user_profile.city "Atlanta"
  user_profile.state "GA"
  user_profile.zip_code "30309"
  user_profile.association :user
end
```

My user_spec test is setup like so:

```
describe "profile" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = User.create(@attr)
      @profile = Factory(:user_profile, :user => @user, :created_at => 1.day.ago)
    end

    it "should have a user profile attribute" do
      @user.should respond_to(:user_profile)
    end

    it "should have the right user profile" do
      @user.user_profile.should == @profile
    end

    it "should destroy associated profile" do
      @user.destroy
      [@profile].each do |user_profile|
        lambda do
          UserProfile.find(user_profile)
        end.should raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
      end
    end
  end
```

My user_profile_spec is setup like so:

```
describe UserProfile do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @attr = { :state => "GA" }
  end

  it "should create a new instance with valid attributes" do
      @user.user_profiles.create!(@attr)
  end


  describe "user associations" do
    before(:each) do
      @user_profile = @user.user_profiles.create(@attr)
    end

    it "should have a user attribute" do
      @user_profile.should respond_to(:user)
    end

    it "should have the right associated user" do
      @user_profile.user_id.should == @user.id
      @user_profile.user.should == @user
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the tests I get "undefined method `user_profiles' for #". How is my test flawed or is my relationship flawed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `has_one` association called `user_profile` (singular). You do not have an association called `user_profiles` (plural).

Comment: I see. When I change it I get "1) UserProfile should create a new instance with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: @user.user_profile.create!(@attr)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_profile_spec.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'"

Comment: For creating the association, you will want to use `create_user_profile`. Instead of `user_profile.create`. The `association.create` method is for collection based associations, `has_many` and the like.