# Can't get this inclusion validation in rails working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

I'm trying to make a test for gender in a model using Rspec - it looks like this:

```
it "should require a valid gender" do
  wrong_gender_student = @student_group.students.create!(@student_attr.merge(gender: "Zlorp"))
  wrong_gender_student.should_not be_valid
end
```

It fails, as expected:

```
1) Student should require a valid gender
 Failure/Error: wrong_gender_student.should_not be_valid
   expected #<Student id: 2, name: "Example Student", gender: "Zlorp", created_at: "2013-05-28 16:25:53", updated_at: "2013-05-28 16:25:53", student_group_id: 1> not to be valid
```

However, when add the code to make it pass:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gender, :name

  belongs_to :student_group
  has_many   :subjects
  has_many   :characteristics

  VALID_GENDERS = %w(Male Female Transgender)

  validates :gender, inclusion: { :in => VALID_GENDERS,
                                :message => "%{value} is not a valid gender" }

end
```

It still fails, and it seems as though the validation test is working, but it's not being passed "Zlorp" - gender below is 'Nil'

```
  1) Student should require a valid gender
 Failure/Error: association_attr #this is a list of variables in spec_helper.rb
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Gender  is not a valid gender
```

**EDIT**: Here's association_attr:

```
def association_attr
  # User attritbutes 
  @user = Factory(:user)

  # Student_group
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.create!(@student_group_attr)
  # Student_group attributes
  @student_group_attr = { name: "4a" }

  # Student 
  @student = @student_group.students.create!(@student_attr)
  # Student attributes
  @student_attr = { gender: "Female", name: "Example Student" }

  # Subject
  @subject = @student.subjects.create!(@subject_attr)
  # Subject attributes
  @subject_attr = { name: "English", end_date: @date }
  @date = Date.today+180

  # Goal
  @goal = @subject.goals.create!(@goal_attr)
  # Goal attributes
  @goal_attr = { goal: "To unlearn the evil" }

  # Characteristic
  @characteristic = @student.characteristics.create!(@char_attr)
  # Characteristic attributes
  @char_attr = { characteristic: "Dyslexic" }

  # Age_group
  # For has_one associations use 'create_object'
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479083/ruby-on-rails-3-has-one-association-testing
  @age = @student_group.create_age!(@age_attr)
  # Age attributes
  @age_attr = { age: "older adults"}
end
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you added `attr_accessible :gender` ?

Comment: yeah, will edit to include full student.rb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is what you do in the first line

```
@student_group.students.create!
```

That raises an error (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) because that's what create! does when you try to save an invalid record. You don't even get to the second line where you test for validity. What you need to do is

```
 wrong_gender_student = @student_group.students.new(@student_attr.merge(gender: "Zlorp"))
 wrong_gender_student.should_not be_valid
```

Additionally, this has the advantage of not hitting the database, which you don't need for this kind of test.

Comment: still got the same error - editing to include association_attr in case the error is there.  thanks!

Comment: took out the create! in association_attr and that fixed it.  cheers!